# Changing values of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, cin, reversi

I'm new to c++ and as my first assignment was to make a game of reversi, but I'm having problems when it comes to the input of the players in the playGame function. So when i cin x and y, it will change the value of the board array[x][y] from empty or '' to 'B'. I also don't know how to refer the array to the function. I'm sorry if these questions are silly to some but forgive me I'm self-learning here. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void displayTop();
void displayAlpha();
void displayNum();
int displayMenu();
void displayBoard();
char displayHelp();
void playGame();
int num = 8;
char board [8][8] = {

' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
' ',' ',' ','W','B',' ',' ',' ',
' ',' ',' ','B','W',' ',' ',' ',
' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',

};

int main() {
    int choice = displayMenu();
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            displayBoard();
            break;
        case 2:
            displayHelp();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please enter a valid choice." << endl;
            break;
    }
    playGame();

}
void displayBoard(){


    displayTop();

    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
        displayNum();
        cout << "   |";

        for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++){
            cout << board[row][column] << "   |";
        }
        cout << endl;
        displayTop();

    }

    displayAlpha();

}

void displayTop(){
    cout << "    ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        cout << "+----";
    }
    cout << endl;

}

void displayAlpha(){
    cout << "   ";
    for( char i = 'a'; i <= 'h'; i++ ) {
    cout << "    " << i ;
    }
}

void displayNum(){
    if (num > 0) {
        cout << num;
        num = num - 1;

    }
}

int displayMenu(){
    int answer = 0;
    cout << "Othello\n\n"
    << "1.New Game\n2.Help\n3.Quit\nYour Choice: ";
    cin >> answer;
    system("clear");
    return answer;

}

char displayHelp(){
    char answer = ' ';
    cout << "How to play Othello\n\nThe object of the game is to have     the majority of your colour discs on the board at the end of the     game.\n\nInput the cell where you want to place your disc in the form of     (a-z 1-8) without the bracket and includng the space.\n\nThe one with the     most discs wins!!!!\n\nSo, are you ready to play? (y or n)\n\nYour Choice:    ";
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 'y')
        displayBoard();

    return answer;
}

void playGame(){
    int plW = 2;
    int plB = 2;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    char player = 'B';
    for(;;){
        cout << "\n\nScore: W = " << plW << " B = " << plB;
        cout << "\nPlayer: " << player;
        cout << "\nPlease make your move : ";
        cin >> x >> y;
        cout << endl;

        if (x < 9 && y < 9) {
            board[x-1][y-1] = player;
            displayBoard();
        } else {
            cout << "Invalid Input";
        }

        if (player == 'B') {
            plB++;
            player = 'W';

        } else {
            plW++;
            player = 'B';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Is your question is `how to refer an array to a function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the input from cin and hold on to it in your game board, you need your playGame() function to have a reference to the game board. You could declare your game board array before main to make it global in scope, which would allow you to reference it in any of the functions in this file.

```
char board[8][8] = {

{' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',}
{' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',}
{' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',}
{' ',' ',' ','W','B',' ',' ',' ',}
{' ',' ',' ','B','W',' ',' ',' ',}
{' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',}
{' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',}
{' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',}

};

int main() {
int choice = displayMenu();
switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        displayBoard();
        break;
    case 2:
        displayHelp();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Please enter a valid choice." << endl;
        break;
}
playGame();

}
```

then in playGame

```
void playGame(){
int plW = 0;
int plB = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
char player = 'B';

cout << "\n\nScore: W = " << plW << " B = " << plB;
cout << "\nPlayer: " << player;
cout << "\nPlease make your move : ";
cin >> x >> y;

board[x][y]=player;
}
```

To display the board:

```
displayBoard(){

    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
        cout << "   |";

        for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++){
             cout << board[row][column] << "   |";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Not sure about the formatting here, you can fix that yourself I think.

Lastly you need to repeatedly call playGame() and diplayBoard(), so put your switch statement into a while loop with a break condition. This means you will continue to query the player for input (remember to switch the player), read his move and put it in your array, and display the board. Break out of the while loop when the user types Exit, or something along those lines.

Comment: The definition of boards needs more `{` and `}` to group each row. Currently, it is just 64 chars

Comment: Good catch, I had copied his board without checking!

Comment: Still the board doesn't change when i run the code. Plus i keep getting TERM environment variable not set on my display.

Comment: Your display functions are wrong. You need to loop through the board array and print out the characters in the array. I see you have a loop where you do this, but it's not contained in a function. Put it in a function and call it whenever you want to display the updated board.

Comment: Im really sorry but i don't get what you mean. If you can show me what are you saying.

Comment: Ok i see now thanks a lot. If there's anything I'm stuck with I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Mahmoud Dawlatly Cool. Remember to mark my answer if it helped you out :)

Comment: @cwuertz Now everything is working out alright. However , the minute I input my values the side column showing the numbers is gone. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: What do you mean by side column?

Comment: The column in the display showing the numbers from 8 to 1. The displayNum() function.

Comment: It's because you decrement num until it equals zero after calling displayNum eight times in your loop. Then the next time it is called, num is zero and doesn't pass your if num > 0 condition. You could reset it to 8 at the end of your nested loops in displayBoard

Comment: I'm really sorry @cwuertz that was too easy to slip by me. Thank again.

Comment: No worries. Good luck!